# sql - how do I pick up all services that are open and latest of those ended - complicated

Tags: greatest-n-per-group, date, window-functions

I am having issue capturing all rows that I need. A client can have number of services including same service again if that is an additional help, all services ended will have an end date and all open will be null. The start date can different even for same service.

My current code captures:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

As shown on the above picture it should be latest service unless the end date is null

Here is my current code:

```
select
  s.id
 ,s.service
 ,s.service_id
 ,s.commitment_start_date
 ,s.commitment_end_date
from services
inner join dmrt.dm_per p on (p.id = s.id)
where s.commitment_start_date = (
    select max(s2.commitment_start_date)
    from service s2
    where s2.person_id = s.person_id
    and s2.service_id = s.service_id
```

Comment: "*latest service*" - By `start date` or by `end date`? Can the same service be listed more than once with the same start or end date?

Comment: How your original data looks like? Do you want Max(start_date) for each ID? Except if end_date is null? What in this case? You want all nulls + max start_date row?

Comment: Also what is the DB that you use? MSSQL\MYSQL\Oracle\etc.?

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Yes, same services can be used more than once... e.g. they can have same services to give extra care

Comment: @MichaelCherevko If it works I do want Max (start_date) for each ID unless the end_date is null. Also need to consider if the same service has ended and another service open than only want services that are open. Basically I want the latest services open unless there is null end_date. I am using MSSQL - Sybase - sap

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use a row-numbering solution

```
SELECT
  s.id
 ,s.service
 ,s.service_id
 ,s.commitment_start_date
 ,s.commitment_end_date
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.end_date DESC) AS rn
    FROM services s
) s
JOIN dmrt.dm_per p ON p.id = s.id
WHERE (s.rn = 1 OR s.end_date IS NULL);
```